# create svg hexagon points with only only a length

Tags: javascript, svg, trigonometry

I am trying to create a hexagon using an svg polygon.

I want to create the x and why coordinates but my code is not working.

I thought I could use the trig functions by transforming each point by 60 degrees.

It is clearly not working.

```js
const radius = 25;

const points = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((n) => {
    const current = n * 60;

    return [radius * Math.cos(current), -radius * Math.sin(current)];
  }).map((p) => p.join(','))
  .join(' ');

document.querySelector('polygon')
  .setAttribute("points", "100,0 50,0 100,100");
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polygon points="" style="fill: #ccffcc; stroke: red;stroke-width: 3;"
    />
   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/), it can be converted to javascript like:

```js
const radius = 50;
const height = 200;
const width = 200;

const points = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((n, i) => {
    var angle_deg = 60 * i - 30;
    var angle_rad = Math.PI / 180 * angle_deg;
    return [width/2 + radius * Math.cos(angle_rad), height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle_rad)];
  }).map((p) => p.join(','))
  .join(' ');

document.querySelector('polygon')
  .setAttribute("points", points);
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polygon points="" style="fill: #ccffcc; stroke: red;stroke-width: 3;"
    />
   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many indexes in the example above and your actually adding commas in your first join when you don't need to be. Here is a cleaned-up version.

```
const generateHexPoints = (radius, height, width) => {
    const hexPoints = new Array(6)
    for (let i = 0; i < hexPoints.length; i++) {
        const angleDeg = 60 * i - 30
        const angleRad = (Math.PI / 180) * angleDeg;
        hexPoints[i] = [
            width/2 + radius * Math.cos(angleRad),
            height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angleRad)
        ];
    }
    return hexPoints.map((p) => p.join(' ')).join(' ')
}
```